# 14.04 microphone noice buzzing sounds

Tags: 14.04, troubleshooting

My Microphone started acting up badly this morning has a loud buzz, it has got to be software it was working fine last night installed updates and shutdown last night and boom here we are, oh and i have a Microphone jack microphone and a internal mic, both are acting up... Please help

PLEASE help i need to use skype.

Dafull97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the driver packages:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` && sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Then reboot.